# How to Use A Custom Post Type as Taxonomy for Another Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

Having:

I have two Custom Post Types; one is called `movies` with some detailed meta-boxes. I also have another Custom Post Types called `directors` again with some detailed metabolites like `[name, nationality, gender, age, ...]`.

To Do:

Can you please let hoe I can use the `directors` like taxonomy for `movies` in a way that in future I can query the wp on movies that come from a `name` or `nationality` or... any field listed on `directors`?

I know I can somehow create taxonomies for the `movies` but I need to create an stand alone table/mechanism  to hold directors no mater they have any movie or not

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to create any taxonomies or use directors as taxonomy.

All you need is to add `director_id` field to movies.  So when you edit a movie, you can select it’s director.

Later you can use meta queries to show all movies directed by given person.

Comment: Thanks Kryzyiek, but how can I load data to the `director_id` from director CPT?